# Updating Field in the Form in Odoo respect to change in value of another Field?

Tags: odoo

I developed a Location Module in Odoo where I can add country's & states related to that Country. Then Iam calling this module in another Module Where I have to do like:- when selecting a country, it should automatically populate the states belong to that country in the state field.How this can be done? I tried Onchange function,But didnt worked? I will Provide my model & view code here below.

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class peniel(models.Model):
    _name='peniel'

    name = fields.Char(string="Name")
    product = fields.Many2one('product.template', string='Product', required=True)
    employee = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string='Employee', required=True)
    customer = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Customer', required=True)
    country = fields.Many2one('location', string='Country', required=True)
    state = fields.Many2one('state', string='State', required=True)
    date_d = fields.Date(string="Date Activity")
    comment = fields.Text(string="Comments")



   @api.onchange('country')
   def onchange_country(self):
    if self.country:
        self.state = self.country.state
```

View File will be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="action_peniel" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Peniel </field>
            <field name="res_model">peniel</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="search_view_id" eval="False"/>
            <field name="context">{}</field>
            <field name="help">Create new Record</field>

        </record>

        <menuitem name="Peniel" id="peniel_roof" sequence="60"/>

        <menuitem id="menu_peniel_roof" name="Peniel" parent="peniel_roof" sequence="1"/>

        <menuitem action="action_peniel" id="menu_action_peniel" parent="menu_peniel_roof" sequence="20"/>

        <record id="view_location_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">peniel.tree</field>
            <field name="model">peniel</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Peniel">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="product"/>
                    <field name="employee"/>
                    <field name="customer"/>
                    <field name="country"/>
                    <field name="state"/>
                    <field name="date_d"/>
                    <field name="comment"/>
                </tree> 
            </field>    

        </record>


        <record id="view_location_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">peniel.form</field>
            <field name="model">peniel</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Peniel">
                    <group>
                       <field name="name"/>
                       <field name="product"/>
                       <field name="employee"/>
                       <field name="customer"/>
                       <field name="country"/>
                       <field name="state"/>
                       <field name="date_d"/>
                       <field name="comment"/>
                    </group>
                </form> 
            </field>    

        </record>       

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Where is your code which have you tried with making `onchange` function ?

Comment: @Odedra Updated.... Please check...

Comment: Check `@api.onchange('country')` indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Their is no require of `onchange` function. We may handle with below tricks.

Replace your field definition

```
country = fields.Many2one('location', string='Country', required=True)
state = fields.Many2one('state', string='State', required=True)
```

with

```
country = fields.Many2one('res.country', string='Country', required=True)
state = fields.Many2one('res.country.state', string='State', required=True)
```

Now change field on `.xml` side:

Replace field

```
<field name="state"/>
```

with

```
<field name="state" domain="[('country_id', '=', country)]"/>
```